# How to delete S3 object in AWS-SDK-Go?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I want to delete `bucket/userID`.
But there are many files under `bucket/userID`

I have to implement to delete `bucket/userID`, need using `ListObjects` then `DeleteObjects`.
The function `ListObjects` returns `result.Contents` is `[]*s3.Object`
But `DeleteObjects` needs `[]*s3.ObjectIdentifier`.

I can't convert `[]*s3.Object` to `[]*s3.ObjectIdentifier`.
In this code, error occurred `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

```
type Object struct {
    _ struct{} `type:"structure"`

     ETag *string `type:"string"`
     Key *string `min:"1" type:"string"`
    LastModified *time.Time `type:"timestamp" 
    timestampFormat:"iso8601"`
    Owner *Owner `type:"structure"`
    Size *int64 `type:"integer"`
    StorageClass *string `type:"string" enum:"ObjectStorageClass"`
}

type ObjectIdentifier struct {
    _ struct{} `type:"structure"`

    Key *string `min:"1" type:"string" required:"true"`
    VersionId *string `type:"string"`
}

objects := getObjects() // return []*s3.Object
a := make([]*s3.ObjectIdentifier, len(objects))

for i, v := range objects {
        a[i].Key = v.Key
}
```

`a[i].Key = v.Key` is error.
How to implement to delete `bucket/userID`?

Answer (score 2):

```
// Create a new AWS session
session, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String("us-west-1"),
})

// Create an S3 client
svc := s3.New(session)

// Prepare the delete object input
input := &s3.DeleteObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("my-demo-bucket"), // s3 bucket name
    Key:    aws.String("file.txt"), // file name
}

// Delete the object
_, err = svc.DeleteObject(input)
if err != nil {
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

ref - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.DeleteObject

Answer (score 0):

The Go developer guide has a topic, with code, on deleting all objects in a bucket: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-basic-bucket-operations.html#s3-examples-bucket-ops-delete-all-bucket-items

Answer (score 0):

In you implementation, `a := make([]*s3.ObjectIdentifier, len(objects))` only declares those variables. It does not initialize the array for every struct. As a result, it would create a nil pointer exception.

You would need to initialize all struct in your iteration:

```
...
for i, v := range objects {
        a[i] = &s3.ObjectIdentifier{
                Key: v.Key,  
        }
}
```

After you construct the `[]*s3.ObjectIdentifier`, you could call `DeleteObjects` with `DeleteObjectsInput` parameters according to AWS Golang's doc.